# incremental counter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

My question is pretty simple but answer might be tricky.

I'm in PHP and I want to manage manually a unique ID for my objects.
What is tricky is to manage atomicity. I dont want that 2 elements get the same ID.

"Elements" are grouped in "Groups". In each group I want elements ID starting from 1 and grow incrementally for each insert in that group.

My first solution is to have a "lastID" column in the table "Groups" :

```
CREATE TABLE groups ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, lastId INT )
CREATE TABLE elements ( myId INT, multiple values ...)
```

**In order to avoid many elements with the same ID, I have to update lastId and select it in an atomic SQL Query.**

After that, one retrieved, I have a unique ID that can't be picked again and I can insert my element.

My question is how to solve the bold part ? My database is MySQL with MyISAM engine so there is no transaction support.

```
UPDATE groups 
SET lastId = lastId + 1 
WHERE id = 42

SELECT lastId 
FROM groups
WHERE id = 42
```

Is there something more atomic than these 2 requests ?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the auto increment id? This is exactly the problem it was designed to solve.

Comment: I need to have many id sequences, on per group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE groups SET lastId = last_insert_id(lastId + 1)
```

and then you can get your new id with

```
SELECT last_insert_id()
```

Using `last_insert_id` with a parameter will store the value and return it when you call it later.
This method of generating autonumbers works best with MyISAM tables having only a few rows (MyISAM always locks the entire table). It also has the benefit of not locking the table for the duration of the transaction (which will happen if it is an InnoDB table).

This is from the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html):

> If expr is given as an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the
>   argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next
>   value to be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID(). This can be used to simulate
>   sequences:
>
> Create a table to hold the sequence counter and initialize it:

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL); 
INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
```

> Use the table to generate sequence numbers like this:

```
UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

> The UPDATE statement increments the sequence counter
>   and causes the next call to LAST_INSERT_ID() to return the updated
>   value. The SELECT statement retrieves that value. The
>   mysql_insert_id() C API function can also be used to get the value.
>   See Section 21.8.3.37, “mysql_insert_id()”.
>
> You can generate sequences without calling LAST_INSERT_ID(), but the
>   utility of using the function this way is that the ID value is
>   maintained in the server as the last automatically generated value. It
>   is multi-user safe because multiple clients can issue the UPDATE
>   statement and get their own sequence value with the SELECT statement
>   (or mysql_insert_id()), without affecting or being affected by other
>   clients that generate their own sequence values.

Comment: This is not atomic. Fore example, if there is two consecutive UPDATE followed by two consecutive SELECT, the same id will be returned by the seles

Comment: Only if you do two consecutive updates on the same connection. It's similar to the way you would normally use last_insert_id (you have to use it right after the insert but it is safe from other connections inserting things).

Comment: Do you mean if two different users run an update at the same time, the last_insert_id cannot return the same value to each user ? If this is sure, this is a good answer but I see that MyISAM locks the table ! what happens if a user update the locked table ?? My table has millions records !

Comment: Yes, last_insert_id is different for every connection. Otherwise it will get messed up when multiple users insert things simultaneously. The table is locked only during the actual update (a few miliseconds) while it is locked the next update query will wait and after the 1-st update is done the 2-nd will start. As i noted in the answer this is useful to generate autonumbers using a special 'next_number' table which usually has one row.

Comment: For my information, I understand that LAST_INSERT_ID only works if the connection is the same between update and select. I then have to make sure that my PHP Framework keep the connection open, do I ? I hope that CodeIgniter keeps it open.

Comment: Yes. If the connection drops before you get the last_insert_id your number will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

One option is for you to use the nifty MyISAM feature that let's auto_increment values be incremented for each group.

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX elements_ix1 ON elements (groupId, myID)

myID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

That's more "atomic" than anything that involves updating a separate table. Note that this only works for MyISAM, not InnoDB.

---

excerpt from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

MyISAM Notes

For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

Comment: This looks very nice, it worth a +1. But I'm not sure I want to stick my application behaviour to the database engine. I want it to be portable to another engine.

Comment: Actually my development environment is on InnoDB to force foreign keys checks. And my production environment is on MyISAM, without FK.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your MySQL installation also has InnoDB engine which does support transactions.  You just need to change the engine type of you tables.

Comment: Actually my development environment is on InnoDB to force foreign keys checks. And my production environment is on MyISAM, without FK.

Comment: Can you not change the engines in the production DB tables?  You really should match your two environments as MyISAM and InnoDB have totally different behaviors.

Comment: No I can't. I depend on my provider. I use innoDB in dev environment to force foreign key checks because this shows out errors that MyISAM don't.